# Connect to Derby Database using db visualiser

Tags: database, derby, dbvisualizer

I'm trying to connect to a derby database using DB visualiser but I'm not sure where to start.

In my Derby/bin folder I have a folder called COMPANYDB

so I'm assuming this is the database itself.

so in the connection details I'm trying to connect to a database URL of

derby://localhost:8011/COMPANYDB

but it fails.

Is there meant to be a Userid and password for a derby database? Or am I just using the wrong syntax for the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Database URL was required in this format

jdbc:derby:C:\Program Files\derby\bin\COMPANYDB